# Rails - Not equal in Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to execute a sql query against a table. I'm experiancing a problem in which I cannot proceed.

How can I use Active Record to query a table where column is not equal
to null? Current query is given below but it's not working as it gives me a null.

```
no_sweets = CookieJar.where(cookie_id: array_of_cookies, artificial_sweetner: !nil).count
```

I want to get count of sweets whose id's are included in `array_of_cookies` and `artificial_sweetner` is not null.

Below code works just fine but I need it in Rails way or say I'll need objects to manipulate.

```
no_sweets = CookieReportingDb.connection.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM cookie_db_new.cookie_jars where artificial_sweetner is not null and cookie_id IN (#{array_of_cookies.join(', ')})").first
```

I'm using ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just put the where clause as string inside the `where` call:

```
no_sweets = CookieJar.where("artificial_sweetner is not null").where(cookie_id: array_of_cookies).count
```

Or in **Rails 4** You can do something like this:

```
no_sweets = CookieJar.where.not(artificial_sweetner: nil).where(cookie_id: array_of_cookies).count
```

Comment: First one didn't worked since NOT is not supported by Rails 3.2, new edited code worked like a charm, thank you. Seems like cannot upvote for some time, will do after some time.

Comment: Yes you are right, i should update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3

```
no_sweets = CookieJar.where(cookie_id: array_of_cookies).where("artificial_sweetner IS NOT NULL").count
```

Rails 4

```
no_sweets = CookieJar.where(cookie_id: array_of_cookies).where.not(artificial_sweetner: nil).count
```

Comment: I'm getting "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
" error when using .not, .not chaining not working with my version of Rails I guess.